# Will Windows free the user-provided stack when the thread is exited?

Tags: winapi

According to Wikipedia, [Win32 Thread Information Block: Stack information stored in the TIB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block#Stack_information_stored_in_the_TIB), I should be able to change a thread's stack by updating `RSP` and the `TIB`.

The problem is, what will happen with my custom stack when the thread is exited? Will Windows free it using `VirtualFree()`, or do I need to free it manually?

Comment: Why do you need to do this in the first place? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm writing a compatibility layer similar to Wine but the executable I'm going to run need to specify it own stack when spawning a thread.

Comment: Modifying undocumented fields in the TIB is naturally not supported. You have wandered into undefined behavior and all bets are off.

Comment: I understand that. The problem is it seems like this is the only way to run a thread with a custom stack on Windows.

Comment: system call `ZwFreeVirtualMemory` on `Teb->DeallocationStack`. so if you update this member - system free it. however - for what change stack ? you also can convert thread to fiber and create additional fiber(s). run on fiber stack. can set custom stack (need update fiels in Teb), run on it, and before exit, return to native stack..

Comment: Thanks for the information. Cloud you make that into an answer instead so I can accept it?

Comment: Also see [Using fibers to expand a thread’s stack at runtime](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200602-00/?p=103819).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @RbMm's suggestion:

> system call `ZwFreeVirtualMemory` on `Teb->DeallocationStack`. so, if
> you update this member - system free it. however - for what change
> stack? you also can convert thread to fiber and create additional
> fiber(s). run on fiber stack. can set custom stack (need update fiels
> in Teb), run on it, and before exit, return to native stack.